# Change colors of code completion pop-up in Webstorm

Tags: webstorm

I would like to change the font colors of the auto-complete hints that in the pop up. The light purple & grey on light blue isn't very readable for me. The different themes don't seem to change it and I can't find a setting in the fonts & colors for it.

- Webstorm 11
- OS X

[image]

Comment: Also if anyone has tips or a link to a good webstorm theme for someone with poor eyesight that would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what you have got there.

Comment: Added a screenshot. It actually doesn't look as bad on the screenshot as in my IDE. They greys are actually harder for me to see in the live rendering.

Comment: As far as I'm aware (Windows user) these are standard colors. The only thing you may try is to change GUI Theme at `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Theme`. It's different to Color Schema that mainly affects editor area.